# when is the normal image used in QNormalDiffuseMapMaterial with qt

Tags: image, qt3d

I am new at qt3d and try to learn what these things do, so there came up the following question:
When does the program displays the normal and when the diffuse TextureImage of QNormalDiffuseMapMaterial?

In the following code, *red.png* is a big red picture and *green.png* is a big green picture, and I am sure that the paths are ok.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>

#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>
#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>

#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QCuboidMesh>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QNormalDiffuseMapMaterial>

#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QTextureImage>

Qt3DCore::QEntity* createScene(){
    auto rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;

    auto cuboid = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);

    auto cuboidMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh;

    auto cuboidTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform;

    auto cuboidMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QNormalDiffuseMapMaterial;
    cuboidMaterial->setAmbient(QColor::fromRgbF(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    auto normalCuboidImage = new Qt3DRender::QTextureImage;
    auto diffuseCuboidImage = new Qt3DRender::QTextureImage;
    normalCuboidImage->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/images/green.png"));
    diffuseCuboidImage->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/images/red.png"));
    cuboidMaterial->normal()->addTextureImage(normalCuboidImage);
    cuboidMaterial->diffuse()->addTextureImage(diffuseCuboidImage);

    cuboid->addComponent(cuboidMesh);
    cuboid->addComponent(cuboidTransform);
    cuboid->addComponent(cuboidMaterial);

    return rootEntity;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow window;

    auto scene = createScene();

    window.setRootEntity(scene);

    window.camera()->setPosition(QVector3D(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
    window.camera()->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I only see a big red cube, but nothing is green. So when is the normal TextureImage used?

I am using Qt 5.14.1 on windows.

Comment: Do you understand what a normal map actually is? It doesn't sound like you do - maybe read the [related wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping). It doesn't make sense to provide an all green normal texture.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I didn't understand!